# Uploading file on the wrong folder with PHP

Tags: php

I'm uploading pictures using AngularJS and PHP.
On the server side, my code looks like this:

```
<?php
    $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $destination = '/home1/cccctang/public_html/miquelimarc/uploads' . $filename;
    move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] , $destination ); 
?>
```

Even that the folder seems to be properly defined, it keeps uploading files to the root folder (where the .php file is).

What am I missing?

Comment: You are missing `/` after `uploads`

Comment: Jesus christ. OK, send it as an answer and I mark as valid.

Comment: Looks like someone already **Vampired my comment into an answer** thanks @mamta

Comment: @RiggsFolly you have earlier used \ in your comment not  this /. :)

Comment: Well Am i bovered?

Comment: I think the only solution is a fight to the death with dull knives. Choose a time and place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forget to write /

```
$destination = '/home1/cccctang/public_html/miquelimarc/uploads/' . $filename;
```